# I came across this book in Numerical Methods. I need the title. Only found scanned pages of the book. But I don't know its title

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I came across this book in Numerical Methods. I need the title. Only found scanned pages of the book. But I don't know its title. Attached are the scanned images.

> [image: 1]
> [image]

For more images look here: [$1$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vZ49.jpg),[$2$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUq25.jpg),[$3$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug4iP.jpg),[$4$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iku4p.jpg).

Comment: And where are those images?

Comment: Why not just google some phrases in these pages, especially in google-books?

Comment: Thanks the title has been given in the comment below.

Comment: @HarlenEmlyn The title is an answer below, but it is also in the header of the second page that you posted!

Comment: I am voting to close this question because : We have nothing useful here. Image has that title. No Math knowledge is necessary. No user can get Math knowledge out of the Question.

Answer (score 4):

The title appears in the images: **Numerical Methods in Engineering and Science**.  The author is B.S. Grewal.

Comment: Thanks a lot I have it now.